Get all nested group users by Power Automate action
I'm trying to get all owners on a SharePoint site using a Power Automate action, and I'm facing a few issues:

It seems there is no API or action that can return all nested group users at once.
If the nested group levels are dynamic (i.e., it's not possible to know how many levels of sub-groups there are), how can I handle the looping in Power Automate?

Below is an example structure of the SharePoint Site Owner Group from which I would like to retrieve all users:
Site Owner 
|-- Peter
|-- AD Group - 1
    |-- Ben
    |-- AD Group - 2
        |-- Michael
        |-- maybe more sub-groups here...
|-- AD Group - 3
    |-- Ken

Are there any methods or suggestions that can help me retrieve all users from the above structure?
Thank you.

Get the Site Groups of your SharePoint Site,
https://<your-site-url>/_api/web/sitegroups

Then Identify the owners group and note down it's group Id.
After that get Members of that Group, in your case owners of the site,
https://<your-site-url>/_api/web/sitegroups(<group-id>)/users

Use power automate action i.e. Send an HTTP request to SharePoint. It will be automated and give you required result.
Reference,
Working with the SharePoint Send HTTP Request flow action in Power Automate

Thank you for your answers. But I'm looking for a method getting all nested group user information also. The rest api you suggested will only return the first level of nested group info.

Eventually I solved the problem with a work around. For others may face the same issue as a reference.

Add an action 'Send an HTTP request to SharePoint' to get your group of users.



You can add a Condition to check the return from Step 1. This step is looking for the return with empty email and 'principalType' equal to '4' which is a nested group.


Add an action 'Send an HTTP request V2' of Office 365 Group with following URL:


https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/@{Group ID from Step 1 return)}/transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.user?$count=true

Also add a CustomHeader:
ConsistencyLevel: eventual


Above steps should be able to get all user with nested group users.
